# beamer - multicol - text getting cut at the bottom

Tags: beamer, enumerate, multicol

My code is this:

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia,multicol,tikz,longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
\useinnertheme[]{rectangles}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\transc}{\fontsize{13}{22}\selectfont}
\title[Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 01.02 -- part 2]{Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam}
\subtitle{Canto 01, Chapter 02 -- part 2}
\author[\textbf{Divinity and Devotional Service -- part 2}]{\textbf{\Large Divinity and Devotional Service}}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Summary -- Text 16 to 21}
{\transc
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]
    \item the anugraham/mercy of devotees.
    \item service rendered to devotees.
    \item faith in bhakti.
    \item seeking shelter at guru's feet.
    \item eagerness to worship Kṛṣṇa.
    \item performance of bhakti activities.
    \item disappearance of obstacles.
    \item steadiness in bhakti
    \item taste for anything connected to Kṛṣṇa.
    \item firm attachment for Kṛṣṇa
    \item fondness/affection for Kṛṣṇa
    \item devotional love (prema)
    \item vision of Kṛṣṇa's form.
    \item direct experience of Kṛṣṇa's sweetness, qualities.
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: multicol-itemize]

As you can see, point #8 is completely gone and point #14 is partially gone. And there's so much extra space at the top. How do I lift up the entire thing.

Comment: Try `\begin{frame}[t]`.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Works fine with one of the themes, which come with beamer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/btZNx.png (although personally, I would rather use beamer's own columns mechanism)

Comment: @Sigur Tried it. Doesn't help.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 1. Have given the full MWE. 2. My font size is bigger than yours. So I need to get rid of the extra space at the top. 3. Problem with `\begin{columns} ... \end{columns}` is that I have to manually break the column and the enumerate environ also needs to be restarted in the right column.

Comment: Oh! A simple `\vspace*{-2em}` after `\frametitle{Summary -- Text 16 to 21}` did the trick!! Sometimes, these simple things go off the mind..

Comment: @vrgovinda 2. That's why you should never post questions without a MWE 3. That's the point. A presentation relies much more on a clear visual presentation than a document intend for reading. Instead of relying on algorithm to set a break point which might or might not be good, you should be in control over where you list splits.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I agree with you on both points, 2 & 3. The need is such that I have to get it done like this only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\transc` before the multicols will force latex to start a new line. You can safe one line by either moving it into the columns or use an appropriate beamer font macro instead.

In addition to saving this line, you can make your slide less cramped by reducing the space between the lines a bit. This way you will still get a bit of white space around the text, which will make it much more pleasant to look at.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia,multicol,tikz,longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
\useinnertheme[]{rectangles}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\transc}{\fontsize{13}{22}\selectfont}
\title[Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 01.02 -- part 2]{Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam}
\subtitle{Canto 01, Chapter 02 -- part 2}
\author[Divinity and Devotional Service -- part 2]{Divinity and Devotional Service}
\date{}

\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{author}{series=\bfseries,size=\Large}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Summary -- Text 16 to 21}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\fontsize{13}{20}}%
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]
    \item the anugraham/mercy of devotees.
    \item service rendered to devotees.
    \item faith in bhakti.
    \item seeking shelter at guru's feet.
    \item eagerness to worship Kṛṣṇa.
    \item performance of bhakti activities.
    \item disappearance of obstacles.
    \item steadiness in bhakti
    \item taste for anything connected to Kṛṣṇa.
    \item firm attachment for Kṛṣṇa
    \item fondness/affection for Kṛṣṇa
    \item devotional love (prema)
    \item vision of Kṛṣṇa's form.
    \item direct experience of Kṛṣṇa's sweetness, qualities.
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
%}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer. learning the basics of beamer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Oh! A simple `\vspace*{-2em}` after `\frametitle{Summary -- Text 16 to 21}` did the trick!! Sometimes, these simple things go off the mind..